# Responsive Site won't show on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

i know this is not a question about source code, however i need to find the solution. So, This is my [site](http://virusworld.eu/racoongreg).

After i finished making the site, I resized my browser window, the responsive css worked perfectly. However, when I tryied to see my site from my mobile phone the only thing I could was the top bar..

Comment: did you tryed with the emulator of chrome, to see if you have the same result? Also, whet is your phone?

Comment: how can i do that? P.S. i tested with these 2 phones.. Bitmore SP521Q (4GB) and Leagoo Lead 7

Comment: I FOUND IT! I FOUND THE EMULATOR.. I can see the site properly in the emulator.

Comment: Ok I bet you don't use chrome on your mobiles, but the default browser. That's probably why.

I tryed your site on theMicrosoft Edge emulator of Windows 10 Mobile, and it's completely broken. Do you have Microsoft Edge? If so try using the Windows 10 mobile emulator.

 Else, try with Internet Explorer emulator using Windows Mobile emulation or IE7/8

Comment: oh, i dont know it was completely broken, in the chrome emulator it looks nice! Thanks BTW

Comment: Well, it depends of the "audience" there. I mean, if your site is small, and just for friends/mates, you don't care if it's broken in some old or bad browser (like the default of you mobiles) ^^ You probably use some proprieties that are not available on those old browser

Comment: Well the site is for a friend of mine, you is a youtuber!(420 subs). You are right is not that importand. Thank you so much dude.

Comment: I looks really broken to me as well. For starters, you should fix the list of errors that pop up during the [HTML validation](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fvirusworld.eu%2Fracoongreg%2F) of your site. After that, you can go through the [MobileOK validation](https://validator.w3.org/mobile/check?docAddr=http%3A%2F%2Fvirusworld.eu%2Fracoongreg%2F&async=true) which is also available on that site, for your site. Though the MobileOK will probably be less useful than the HTML validation.

Comment: You also might want to look into using something to handle cross-browser differences (ie: vender/browser prefixes). If your going to be doing a lot with websites, I'd recommend getting setup to have it done automatically (via a CSS-preproessor or CSS-postprocessor or something) to do it automatically for you.

Comment: thanks a lot! you are amazing guys!